# Find (and keep) duplicates of sublist in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates, sublist

I have a list of lists (sublist) that contains numbers and I only want to keep those exists in all (sub)lists.

Example:

```
x = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]]

output => [3, 4]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
common = set(x[0])
for l in x[1:]:
    common &= set(l)
print list(common)
```

or:

```
import operator
print reduce(operator.iand, map(set, x))
```

Comment: I originally started with set(), it's fixed now.

Comment: Yep, I posted an answer which modified yours and worked, but by the time I'd got back you edited it. Sadly, stackoverflow won't let me +1 you, since I upvoted, and then undid my upvote. Great answer though!

Answer (score 7):

In one liner:

```
>>> reduce(set.intersection, x[1:], set(x[0]))
set([3, 4])
```

Comment: or list(reduce(set.intersection, x[1:], set(x[0])))

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(a, b):
    return list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))

reduce(f, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of solving, almost same as nadia but without using reduce, and i use map:

```
>>> x = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 6, 7]]
>>> set.intersection(*map(set,x))
set([3, 4])
>>>
```