# Keep duplicates in a list in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

I know this is probably an easy answer but I can't figure it out.  What is the best way in Python to keep the duplicates in a list:

```
x = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7]
```

The output should be:

```
[2,6]
```

I found this link: [Find (and keep) duplicates of sublist in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723072/find-and-keep-duplicates-of-sublist-in-python), but I'm still relatively new to Python and I can't get it to work for a simple list.

Comment: Have you tried one of the one liners in that post?

Comment: Do you need to preserve order?

Comment: @DSM -- Looks like we were thinking the same thing ...

Comment: Post the code you are having trouble with, otherwise this is a complete retread of that other question.

Comment: No, I do not need to preserve order.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Not precisely, the other question is also flattening nested lists at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a short way to do it if the list is sorted already:

```
x = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7]

from itertools import groupby
print [key for key,group in groupby(x) if len(list(group)) > 1]
```

Comment: This will also work with python2.6 which is a problem with mine.

Comment: @luchosrock: No, `groupby` groups consecutive elements

Answer (score 16):

I'd use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
x = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]
counts = Counter(x)
output = [value for value, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
```

Here's another version which keeps the order of when the item was first duplicated that only assumes that the sequence passed in contains hashable items and it will work back to when `set` or `yeild` was introduced to the language (whenever that was).

```
def keep_dupes(iterable):
    seen = set()
    dupes = set()
    for x in iterable:
        if x in seen and x not in dupes:
            yield x
            dupes.add(x)
        else:
            seen.add(x)

print list(keep_dupes([1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7]))
```

Comment: However you lose the order of the elements in the output.

Comment: Yep.  There are a lot of situations where this isn't the best way to go.  It also requires the input be hashable... But, it's O(n) even for un-sorted lists which is nice.

Comment: The shortest ordered variant I can think of offhand is `[k for k in OrderedDict.fromkeys(x) if counts[k] > 1]`.

Comment: @DSM -- Why do you need an `OrderedDict` there?  why not just `[k for k in x if counts[k] > 1]`?  Actually, that's better than what I have.  I'll update...

Comment: @mgilson: try it and see.. :^)

Comment: @DSM -- Right...duplicates  (FWIW -- I caught it before I tried it at least ;-)

Comment: I think Python needs an `OrderedSet`.

Comment: Your second code doesn't seem right to me.  `seen.add(e)` and then `if e in seen`?

Comment: @DSM -- I've often wondered why they didn't add an OrderedSet to the language when they added an OrderedDict.  In one of my recent projects, I considered monkey-patching it into the collections module on import ... (I decided against that though ...)

Comment: @DSM -- Apparently not my brightest day.  Needed to switch the order of `seen.add` and the conditional -- Or just scrap that part all together...

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- At least they provide a link to an [implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) in the collections docs

Answer (score 3):

List Comprehension in combination with set() will do exactly what you want.

```py
>>> list(set([i for i in x if x.count(i) > 1]))

[2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

keepin' it simple:

```
array2 = []
aux = 0
aux2=0
for i in x:
    aux2 = i
    if(aux2==aux):
        array2.append(i)
    aux= i
list(set(array2))
```

That should work

Comment: Won't that give `[2,2,6]`?

Comment: @DSM ahaha you're totally right, I edited my answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient but just to get the output, you could try:

```
import numpy as np

def check_for_repeat(check_list):
    repeated_list = []

    for idx in range(len(check_list)):
        elem = check_list[idx]
        check_list[idx] = None

        if elem in temp_list:
            repeated_list.append(elem)

    repeated_list = np.array(repeated_list)

    return list(np.unique(repeated_list))
```