# Finding duplicates in a list and returning True or False(python)

Tags: python, list, function, duplicates, return

I have to write a function which returns True or False depengin on a list.
For example list_a =[1,2,3,4,4] it should return False and if list_a=[1,2,3,4] it should return True.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Write some code. Come back when you hit a wall.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541797/in-python-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-duplicates-in-list

Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
def has_dups(l): 
    return len(set(l)) < len(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a set. Sets are sequences that have only unique elements.

```
def hasNoDuplicates ( lst ):
    return len( lst ) == len( set( lst ) )

>>> hasNoDuplicates( [1,2,3,4,4] )
False
>>> hasNoDuplicates( [1,2,3,4] )
True
```