# Filtering a list python repeated items

Tags: python, list, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find and list duplicates in Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list)

I have this script in Python:

```
routes = Trayect.objects.extra(where=['point_id IN (10,59)'])

for route in routes:
    print route
```

I get this response:

6
**106**
114
**110**
118
158
210
**110**
102
105
**110**
120
195
**106**

As you note "110" route is repeated 3 times and "106" is repeated 2 times.

How i can do for obtain only the repeated number?

I want only **110** and **106**, not others. Just this:

106
110

Im not a native English speaker, and I am learning python. Thanks

***The objects in list are strings

Comment: Does order matter?  Do you need `106, 110` or would `110, 106` be good too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most straightforward way to do it, and also efficient even if `routes` has many items in it:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(routes)

multi_routes = [i for i in counts if counts[i] > 1]
```

Example usage (using numbers, but this will work for hashable type, e.g. strings are fine):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5])
>>> [i for i in c if c[i] > 1]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: It doesnt work, maybe because is a Queryset what i have?

Comment: No error, just a empty list []

Comment: Try `Counter(str(i) for i in routes)` then.

Comment: @ErnestoRuizEscorcia: if `routes` isn't a list, then it's possible that after looping through it once (say for your `print` loop) there's nothing left (agotamiento).  You may want to try `routes = list(Trayect.objects.extra(where=['point_id IN (10,59)']))` too, or remove the `print` loop.

Comment: Got this:  Counter({'110': 3, '210': 1, '195': 1, '158': 1, '120': 1, '261': 1, '6': 1,
 '102': 1, '106': 2, '118': 1, '105': 1})

Comment: If I use the example above I got this error: >>> c = Counter(r)
>>> print [i for i in c if r[i] > 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Trayectoria

Comment: @ErnestoRuizEscorcia: you should use `[i for i in c if c[i] > 1]`, not `r[i] > 1`.

Comment: The list printed is like this:   [<Trayectoria: 6>, <Trayectoria: 106>, <Trayectoria: 110>, <Trayectoria: 118>, <
Trayectoria: 158>, <Trayectoria: 210>, <Trayectoria: 261>, <Trayectoria: 102
>, <Trayectoria: 105>, <Trayectoria: 110>, <Trayectoria: 120>, <Trayectoria: 195
>]

Comment: @ErnestoRuizEscorcia: that means the objects in `routes` aren't strings, but `Trayectoria` instances.  Amber's suggestion of `c = Counter(str(i) for i in routes); print [i for i in c if c[i] > 1]` should work.

Comment: @DSM My bad, if i do that i got an empty list []

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this

```
In [1]: s = "6 106 114 110 118 158 210 110 102 105 110 120 195 106"

In [2]: l = s.split()

In [3]: [x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1]
Out[3]: ['106', '110', '110', '110', '106']

In [4]: set([x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1])
Out[4]: set(['106', '110'])
```

Comment: The objects in list are string, this work with strings too?

Comment: Im using a Querylist : routes = Trayect.objects.extra(where=['point_id IN (10,59)']).   Is that my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
routes = [i for i in set(routes) if routes.count(i) > 1]
```

Comment: This will take approximately O(n^2) time for a list of n routes, which could get inefficient quickly if `routes` is large.