# in python: difference between two lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists like so

```
found = ['CG', 'E6', 'E1', 'E2', 'E4', 'L2', 'E7', 'E5', 'L1', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E2', 'E1^E4', 'E5']
expected = ['E1', 'E2', 'E4', 'E1^E4', 'E6', 'E7', 'L1', 'L2', 'CG', 'E2BS', 'E3']
```

I want to find the differences between both lists.
I have done

```
list(set(expected)-set(found))
```

and

```
list(set(found)-set(expected))
```

Which returns `['E3']` and `['E5']` respectively.

However, the answers I need are:

```
'E3' is missing from found.
'E5' is missing from expected.
There are 2 copies of 'E5' in found.
There are 3 copies of 'E2BS' in found.
There are 2 copies of 'E2' in found.
```

Any help/suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [*collections.Counter*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class will excel at enumerating the differences between multisets:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> found = Counter(['CG', 'E6', 'E1', 'E2', 'E4', 'L2', 'E7', 'E5', 'L1', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E2', 'E1^E4', 'E5'])
>>> expected = Counter(['E1', 'E2', 'E4', 'E1^E4', 'E6', 'E7', 'L1', 'L2', 'CG', 'E2BS', 'E3'])
>>> list((found - expected).elements())
['E2', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E5', 'E5']
>>> list((expected - found).elements())
```

You might also be interested in [difflib.Differ](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/difflib.html#differ-objects):

```
>>> from difflib import Differ
>>> found = ['CG', 'E6', 'E1', 'E2', 'E4', 'L2', 'E7', 'E5', 'L1', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E2BS', 'E2', 'E1^E4', 'E5']
>>> expected = ['E1', 'E2', 'E4', 'E1^E4', 'E6', 'E7', 'L1', 'L2', 'CG', 'E2BS', 'E3']
>>> for d in Differ().compare(expected, found):
...     print(d)

+ CG
+ E6
  E1
  E2
  E4
+ L2
+ E7
+ E5
+ L1
+ E2BS
+ E2BS
+ E2BS
+ E2
  E1^E4
+ E5
- E6
- E7
- L1
- L2
- CG
- E2BS
- E3
```

Comment: Great answer on the difflib.Differ. I began using that sometimes instead of sets.

Answer (score 4):

Leverage the Python [`set` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and [`Counter` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of rolling your own solution:

1. `symmetric_difference`: finds elements that are either in one set or the other, but not both.
2. `intersection`: finds elements in common with the two sets.
3. `difference`: which is essentially what you did by subtracting one set from another

#### Code examples

- ```py
  found.difference(expected) # set(['E5'])
  ```
- ```py
  expected.difference(found) # set(['E3'])
  ```
- ```py
  found.symmetric_difference(expected) # set(['E5', 'E3'])
  ```
- Finding copies of objects: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list) was already referenced. Using that technique gets you all duplicates, and using the resultant `Counter` object, you can find how many duplicates. For example:

  ```py
  collections.Counter(found)['E5'] # 2
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You've already answered the first two:

```
print('{0} missing from found'.format(list(set(expected) - set(found)))
print('{0} missing from expected'.format(list(set(found) - set(expected)))
```

The second two require you to look at counting duplicates in lists, for which there are many solutions to be found online (including this one: [Find and list duplicates in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list)).