# Comparing strings not working

Tags: python, string

I have a list of article titles that I store in a text file and load into a list. I'm trying to compare the current title with all the titles that are in that list like so

```
def duplicate(entry):
    for line in posted_titles:
        print 'Comparing'
        print entry.title
        print line
        if line.lower() == entry.title.lower()
            print 'found duplicate'
            return True
    return False
```

My problem is, this never returns true. When it prints out identical strings for `entry.title` and `line`, it won't flag them as equal. Is there a string compare method or something I should be using?

Edit
After looking at the representation of the strings, `repr(line)` the strings that are being compared look like this:

```
u"Some Article Title About Things And Stuff - Publisher Name"
'Some Article Title About Things And Stuff - Publisher Name'
```

Comment: The representations of the strings are...?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams see the edit at the bottom.

Comment: That's their display. What are their representations? Hint: `repr()`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ahhh I see the problem! `entry.title` has a `u` preceding it and double quotes. `line` has single quotes, no `u`. Thanks :) I'm new to python

Comment: Create a fully working example by constructing a list of two duplicate strings that the code does not detect, so that it is easier for people here to help you.

Comment: It's... a little more detailed than that, but that's a start. http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: If all you're trying to do is find duplicates in a list there are much better ways to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm reading up on that now. Is there an easy way to get them to same encoding simply?

Comment: @Chris: Decode the bytestring with its encoding to turn it into a `unicode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help even more if you would have provided an actual example.

In any way, your problem is the different string encoding in Python 2. `entry.title` is apparently a unicode string (denoted by a `u` before the quotes), while `line` is a normal `str` (or vice-versa).

For all characters that are equally represented in both formats (ASCII characters and probably a few more), the equality comparison will be successful. For other characters it won’t:

```
>>> 'Ä' == u'Ä'
False
```

When doing the comparison in the reversed order, IDLE actually gives a warning here:

```
>>> u'Ä' == 'Ä'
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

You can get a unicode string from a normal string by using `str.decode` and supplying the original encoding. For example `latin1` in my IDLE:

```
>>> 'Ä'.decode('latin1')
u'\xc4'
>>> 'Ä'.decode('latin1') == u'Ä'
True
```

If you know it’s utf-8, you could also specify that. For example the following file saved with utf-8 will also print True:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print('Ä'.decode('utf-8') == u'Ä')
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` is fine for string comparison. Make sure you are dealing with strings

`if str(line).lower() == str(entry.title).lower()`

other possible syntax is boolean expression `str1 is str2`.

Comment: **Never use `is` to compare** unless you know you need to. And you don't.