# Extract list of duplicate values and locations from array

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, duplicates

Given an array `a` of length `N`, which is a list of integers, I want to extract the duplicate values, where I have a seperate list for each value containing the location of the duplicates. In pseudo-math:

```
If |M| > 1:
  val -> M = { i | a[i] == val }
```

Example (`N=11`):

```
a = [0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 1, 3, 3, 2, 10, 10]
```

should give the following lists:

```
3  -> [1, 6, 7]
1  -> [2, 5]
10 -> [9, 10]
```

I added the `python` tag since I'm currently programming in that language (numpy and scipy are available), but I'm more interestead in a general algorithm of how to do it. Code examples are fine, though.

One idea, which I did not yet flesh out: Construct a list of tuples, pairing each entry of `a` with its index: `(i, a[i])`. Sort the list with the second entry as key, then check consecutive entries for which the second entry is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Nope. Read the question again, I need the list of duplicates _and their locations_.

Comment: It's like a 12 character change from that question though. Close enough that you should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to create a dictionary mapping the values to the list of the position where it appears.

This can be done in a simple way with `setdefault`. This can also be done using `defaultdict`.

```
>>> a = [0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 1, 3, 3, 2, 10, 10]
>>> dup={}
>>> for i,x in enumerate(a):
...     dup.setdefault(x,[]).append(i)
...
>>> dup
{0: [0], 1: [2, 5], 2: [8], 3: [1, 6, 7], 6: [3], 8: [4], 10: [9, 10]}
```

Then, actual duplicates can be extracted using set comprehension to filter out elements appearing only once.

```
>>> {i:x for i,x in dup.iteritems() if len(x)>1}
{1: [2, 5], 10: [9, 10], 3: [1, 6, 7]}
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since the set comprehension seems to be the cleaner looking solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation using a python dictionary (actually a defaultdict, for convenience)

```
a = [0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 1, 3, 3, 2, 10, 10]
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for k, item in enumerate(a):
    d[item].append(k)
finalD = {key : value for key, value in d.items() if len(value) > 1}  # Filter dict for items that only occurred once.

print(finalD)    
# {1: [2, 5], 10: [9, 10], 3: [1, 6, 7]}
```

Comment: That final line should really be a dict comprehension

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Good idea.  For some reason I never remember that dictionary comprehensions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Populate a dictionary whose keys are the values of the integers, and whose values are the lists of positions of those keys.  Then go through that dictionary and remove all key/value pairs with only one position.  You will be left with the ones that are duplicated.