# Reporting duplicate from tuple list python (by its index)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Getting the repeated count data from tuple list **item 1** which holds the patient counter `data`...`data[1]`. With below down samples i dont need to consider the duplicates on `data[0]` or `data[2]`

```
import itertools
def getDuplicateinTuple(dataInput):
    seen={}
    return [seen.setdefault(t[0], t) for t in dataInput if t[0] not in seen]

data=[('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'),
('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER2'),
('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER3'),
('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER4'),
('2013 Jul  5 06:57:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'),
('2013 Jul  5 06:56:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER5')]

data1=[('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1', 'COUNTER INFO: : 500 '), 
('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER2', 'COUNTER INFO: : 500 '), 
('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER3', 'COUNTER INFO: : 100 '), 
('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER4', 'COUNTER INFO: : 100 ')]

s=getDuplicateinTuple(data)
print s
s1=getDuplicateinTuple(data1)
print s1
```

and the expected output is :

```
 [('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'), ('2013 Jul  5 06:57:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1')]
```

and actual output is

```
[('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'), ('2013 Jul  5 06:57:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'), ('2013 Jul  5 06:56:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER5')]
```

on same if I give a non duplicate output as in `data1`

expected output :

```
 []
```

but current output:

```
[('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1', 'COUNTER INFO: : 500 ')]
```

Just by comparing the list this can be achieved.
What is the better and suggested way to make achieve this?

I saw some nice stack post on this regards:
 [Find and list duplicates in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list)

Comment: @falsetru : with ref http://ideone.com/DWv7uq data1 print getDuplicateinTuple(data) out is requied as [('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'), ('2013 Jul  5 06:57:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1')] and 
print getDuplicateinTuple(data1) matches as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def getDuplicateinTuple(dataInput):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for t in dataInput:
        item1 = t[1]
        d[item1].append(t)
    return [t for ts in d.itervalues() if len(ts) > 1 for t in ts]

data = [
    ('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'),
    ('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER2'),
    ('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER3'),
    ('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER4'),
    ('2013 Jul  5 06:57:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'),
    ('2013 Jul  5 06:56:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER5')
]

data1 = [
    ('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1', 'COUNTER INFO: : 500 '), 
    ('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER2', 'COUNTER INFO: : 500 '), 
    ('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER3', 'COUNTER INFO: : 100 '), 
    ('2013 Jul  5 04:26:40:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER4', 'COUNTER INFO: : 100 ')
]

print getDuplicateinTuple(data)
# => [('2013 Jul  5 06:56:07:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1'),
#     ('2013 Jul  5 06:57:11:', 'PATIENT:COUNTER1')]
print getDuplicateinTuple(data1)
# => []
```

Comment: if i have to omit timestamp means considering on data[1] not data[0]

Comment: data field contains 2 item data[0] is some time stamp and data[1] is content. if i just want to extract only the content(data[1]) duplication what is the approach.

Comment: In tuple list data if data[1] has been duplicated i want to extract and show the data.

Comment: @Ragav, I updated the answer according to question modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a (default) dictionary to count the occurrences and then filter out the occurrences which are less than one:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for timestamp, counter in data:
    d[counter].append(timestamp)

for counter, timestamps in d.items():
    if len(timestamps) > 1:
        print([(t, counter) for t in timestamps])
```

Comment: if i have to omit time stamp means considering on data[1] not data[0]

Comment: Omit the timestamp in the output? Change last line to `print(counter)`.