# Efficiently find repeated characters in a string

Tags: python, string, performance

I know that the efficiency of this code is not optimal (esp. with gigantic inputs), and I know that there is a way to change this algorithm to handle other data types and not just a repetition in a string (obviously there are only so many characters to search through).

Is there any way I can increase efficiency here?

I tried using a dictionary and the function kept returning 'none' so I tried a list and things worked out fine.

Thanks ahead of time to anyone who can help me out!

```
def find_repeater(string):
    my_list = []
    my_list.append(string[0])

    for i in range (1, len(string)):

        if string[i] in my_list:
            print 'repetition found'
            return (string[i])

        else:
            my_list.append(string[i])

print find_repeater('abca')
```

now with a dictionary....(it keeps printing 'none' to the console)

```
def find_repeater(string):
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict[0] = string[0]

    for i in range (1, len(string)):

        if string[i] in my_dict:
            print 'repetition found'
            return string[i]

        else:
            my_dict[i] = string[i]

print find_repeater('abca')
```

Comment: using a dictionary is the way to go. Show what you tried, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: what if there are multiple repeated letters?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: looks like OP wants to return the letter that is repeated first

Comment: Can you sort the input first?

Comment: If you have working code, which just is not efficient enough, a code-review might be a good course (not yet the case). But anyway, consider using a proper title describing the problem you want help with, instead of just a cry for help. Though you are to be commended for only wanting a slight poke in the right direction instead of the whole solution.

Comment: If this code works, this question would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: you are creating a range for no reason, just iterate over the string, also `my_list = [string[0]]` will do what you want in one assignment

Comment: Sorry everyone, it was my first post. Thanks for the support. Ill be more specific next time.

Comment: @emodendroket: sorting costs O(nlogn) time. Not sure that's very efficient. Most of the bottleneck come from (I reckon) the `in my_list` lookups

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Briefly looking it seems like this runs in quadratic time... anyway the point of sorting is that then all the lookups are much faster.  That may very well not be the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As this is a performance question, let's do some timings:

```
def test_set(xs):
    seen = set()  # O(1) lookups
    for x in xs:
        if x not in seen:
            seen.add(x)
        else:
            return x

import collections

def test_counter(xs):
    freq = collections.Counter(xs)
    for k in freq:
        if freq[k] > 1:
            return k

def test_dict(xs):
    d = {}
    for x in xs:
        if x in d:
            return x
        d[x] = 1

def test_sort(xs):
    ys = sorted(xs)

    for n in range(1, len(xs)):
        if ys[n] == ys[n-1]:
            return ys[n]

##

import sys, timeit
print (sys.version + "\n")
xs = list(range(10000)) + [999]
fns = [p for name, p in globals().items() if name.startswith('test')]
for fn in fns:
    assert fn(xs) == 999
    print ('%50s %.5f' % (fn, timeit.timeit(lambda: fn(xs), number=100)))
```

I'm testing on an list of integers rather than a string (because with a string you can't get more than 256 loops). The results on my machine look like this:

```
3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

                <function test_set at 0x1020f7380> 0.19265
               <function test_dict at 0x1020f7490> 0.12725
               <function test_sort at 0x1020f7518> 0.04683
            <function test_counter at 0x1020f7408> 0.92485
```

So the sort method appears to be the winner. I guess this is because it doesn't waste time creating hashes and allocating dict/set structures. Also, if you don't care about the source list being changed, you can do `xs.sort()` instead of `ys = sorted(xs)`, which gives you zero memory footprint.

On the other side, if repeated items are more probable to occur towards the beginning of the input (as in `xs = 'abcdef' * 10000`), the `set` method will perform the best, as it, unlike `sort` or `Counter`, returns immediately once a repeat is found and doesn't need to preprocess the whole list.  You should also use `set` if you need the *first* repeating element, not just one of them.

`Counter` is a nice tool, but it's not designed for performance, so if you really have to deal with "gigantic inputs", go with sets (if they fit in memory) or mergesort if they don't.

Comment: Wouldn't sort be at an advantage in this example because you already have a list that's sorted for all but one value?  Putting random.shuffle(xs) after setting xs makes sort the worst performer, or about tied with counter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections` to find repeating characters:

```
import collections

freq = collections.Counter("abcda")
for k in freq:
    if freq[k] > 1:
        print k # prints "a"
        break
```

If you want only to find if there are repetitions (without finding the repeated characters):

```
letters = list("abcda")
no_rep = set(letters)
print len(letters) > len(no_rep) # prints 'True' when there are repeating characters
```

Comment: don't think you need to cast the set to a list or make letters a list,`letters = ("abcda")` `len(letters) > len(set(letters))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham right! (thx - fixed), I forgot to remove it (was playing with other options before posting it).

Comment: no worries, +1 was, going to post a Counter answer too, just got too lazy :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def find_repeater(mystr):
    seen = set()  # O(1) lookups
    for char in mystr:
        if char not in seen:
            seen.add(char)
        else:
            print('repetition found')
            return char
```

Comment: OP asked for a dictionary. Should have given both answers, like I did

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, using a dictionary:

```
def find_repeater(string):
    my_list = {}
    my_list[string[0]] = 1
    for i in range (1, len(string)):
        if string[i] in my_list.keys():
            print 'repetition found'
            return (string[i])
        else:
            my_list[string[i]] = 1
print find_repeater('abca')
```

Personally, though, I would use a set here:

```
def find_repeater(string):
    my_list = set()
    my_list.add(string[0])
    for i in range (1, len(string)):
        if string[i] in my_list:
            print 'repetition found'
            return (string[i])
        else:
            my_list.add(string[i])
print find_repeater('abca')
```

Comment: why use range instead of just iterating over the string?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
def return_dupe(string):
    d = {}
    [d.update({k:2}) if k in d else d.update({k:1}) for k in string]
    return [key for key in d if d[key] > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be as simple as:

```
def repeting_count(text):

    working_text = str(text.lower())

    dup = []

    for char in working_text:
        if working_text.count(char) > 1:
            dup.append(char)

        else:
            pass

    for num in dup:
        while dup.count(num) > 1:
            dup.remove(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rec_char(s):
    buf={}
    for c in s:
        try:
            print(buf[c],end=", ")
        except:
            buf[c]=c


rec_char("ABCAB")
```

This function in python3 with time complexity O(n) will print the characters that appear more than once.