# Python: looking for duplicates in list

Tags: python, numpy, count, hashable

I have a list of floats, and I want to know how many duplicates are in it.

I have tried with this:

```
p = t_gw.p(sma, m1, m2)       #p is a 1d numpy array
p_list = list(p)
dup = set([x for x in p_list if p_list.count(x) > 1])
print dup
```

I have also tried to use collections.counter, but I always get the same error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I've looked around in similar questions, but I can't understand what hashable means, why a list (or numpy array) is not hashable and what kind of type should I use.

Comment: possible dublicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list

Comment: you wrap one or more numpy arrays in a list then you make a list comprehension and then you wrap the remaining numpy arrays in a set. for wrapping in a set you must have hashable items. numpy arrays aren't.

Comment: @unixer Not a duplicate, this one's numpy-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numpy-array is two-dimensional. So `list(p)` does not do, what you expect. Use `list(p.flat)` instead.

Or (mis)use numpy's histogram function:

```
cnt, bins = numpy.histogram(p, bins=sorted(set(p.flat))+[float('inf')])
dup = bins[cnt>1]
```

Comment: That was useful! I have only one thing to ask: if `p.shape = (1012, 1)` isn't p a 1d array?

Comment: `shape` has two elements, therefore it is two-dimensional. `p.ravel().shape = (1012,)` is one-dimensional.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out in what are they different: I can only think at both of them as arrays with one column (!)

Comment: In the first case, to get an element you have to write `p[i,0]`, with only one-dimension, `p[i]` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what do you mean by number of duplicates.

An easy way to do this is to use hash:

```
h = {}
arr = [6, 3, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1]
for i in arr:
    if i in h:
        h[i] += 1
    else:
        h[i] =1

print h
```

Now if you mean that duplicates are the values that are used more then once in the list, you can do this with:

```
num = 0
for i in h:
    if h[i] > 1:
        num += 1

print num
```

I think that it is pretty easy to modify it to numpy.

Answer (score -1):

you want to count something in a list ?
why not use the count method of list object ?

```
number = my_list.count(my_float)
```