# python check duplicates key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help trying to write a function for detecting if there is a dictionary which contains multiple keys. So im stuck since when using name_to_age the dictionary will already be unique so I am not sure how I can apply this check.

for e.g

```
# the test function should raise an error since there is 2 duplicate keys
name_to_age = {'Sam': 2, 'Sam': 4, 'Alex: 14}
```

Comment: The title concerns duplicate keys (which are not possible in Python dictionaries), but the question mentions multiple keys. Which do you mean?

Comment: You already know the answer.

Comment: Try to `print name_to_age` and see what happens when you override a key...

Comment: At least in Python 3.4.3, in the interactive console, I was able to issue the command `A = { 'a': 1, 'a': 2 }` without raising an error. The result was the dictionary with the second combination only, which I believe replaced the first one.

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski it shouldn't raise an error because overriding an existing key is perfectly valid. As I wrote in the comment above - try to print your dictionary and see how it looks like.

Comment: The usual way to have a "multidict" in python is just using a normal dict using lists as the values.  Some web frameworks implement a custom class for this because it's a common structure for query strings / GET params - e.g. Django's `QueryDict`

Comment: Updated my answer to allow for the possibility of duplicate keys and provided a function to detect them.

Answer (score 1):

The original question is about writing a function that can detect duplicate keys in a dictionary.  Strictly speaking, a dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys but it can contain objects with identical values: [Multiple identical keys in a Python dict - yes, you can!](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html)

The trick is to use objects instead of strings as keys, and to override the hash comparison (see [How hash collisions are resolved in Python dictionaries](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/02/how-hash-collisions-are-resolved-in.html)):

```
class person(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False


alternate = {person("Andrew") : "Cambridge", person("Barbara") : "Bloomsbury", person("Andrew"): "Corsica"}
print alternate
```

The comments below debate the technical aspects of whether these are duplicate keys or not, but this is a side issue.  Back to the original question, if a dictionary could actually hold duplicate keys, what function would detect them?

To find duplicate keys, you could do this:

```
def list_duplicates(d):
    seen = set()
    duplicates = set( x.name for x in d if x.name in seen or seen.add(x.name) )
    return list( duplicates )
```

(adapted from another question: [Find and list duplicates in Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9835762/584846))

Yes, multidict and querydict structures create lists of values for each key, but those don't address the original question's supposition of duplicate keys.  This answer creates a scenario where duplicate "keys" are possible and provides a function to detect them.

Comment: Disagree.  The keys are the memory location of each object, which is unique. >>> [id(a) for a in alternate]
Out[168]: [4489414544, 4489414352, 4489414480]

Comment: If the keys were truly identical, then doing a check with `is` would yield True (e.g. person("Andrew") is person("Andrew") yields False because two separate objects are created, each residing at their own memory location).

Comment: Also you need to maintain a reference to the exact instance used for the key, because `person.__eq__` isn't defined.  That makes this approach more or less useless.

Comment: How about now, with the `__eq__` method?

Comment: You've now violated the contract of `__eq__`, ie that `x.__eq__(y)` must imply `x.__hash__() == y.__hash__()`

Comment: OK, now it's back in the contract.

Comment: Updated to use any dictionary key.  Don't know about this contract, @Eric, can you show a reference to it?

Comment: See [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__): _"The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value"_. You're inheriting `object.__hash__`, which conflicts with your `__eq__`. I'd argue that you do not want an `__eq__` here at all

Comment: That's how it started, in fact.  @wim thought otherwise.

Comment: I don't think otherwise - my point is that to have a useful dict, you need a useful `__eq__` method (i.e. something better than identity).  But if you implement `__eq__` you have to take care to implement `__hash__` correctly.  There is no way to win with the approach proposed in this answer, if you need a multidict you should use a dict with lists as the values.