# How to find duplicates in a list without creating a separate list?

Tags: python

How to find the duplicates in a list without creating any other list?

Example

```
A = [1,2,1,3,4,5,4]
```

At the end

```
A = [1,4]
```

Comment: are you talking about removing non dupes or what exactly?

Comment: If there are three `4`'s in the original list, do you want the result to have two `4`'s or one?

Comment: Also, do you care about order? Can the result be `[4, 1]`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list

Comment: 1)I dont care about order. 2) Yes am taking about removing duplicates.3) If there are three 4's in the original list, i want result to have one 4

Comment: Why don't you want to create another list? What about a set or other container?

Comment: @Nidhi, did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept it :).

Answer (score 2):

So you want a function which takes a list, A, and mutates that list to contain only those elements which were originally duplicated? I assume the restriction on creating new lists applies to any new collection. It is best to be as clear as possible of the requirements when asking a question about algorithms.

It seems an odd requirement that no other collections be made in this algorithm, but it is possible.
A simple but inefficient solution would be to approach it like this:

- for each element, `x`

  - set a boolean flag value, for example, `hasDuplicates` to `false`
  - for each element right of `x`, `y`

    - if `y` is a duplicate of `x`, remove it and set `hasDuplicates` to `true`
  - if `hasDuplicates` is false, remove `x`

If the restriction of not creating another collection can be relaxed, or if the result of the algorithm can be a new list rather than the old one modified, you will find much more (time) efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: The psuedo algorithm I gave has quadratic runtime (`O(n^2)`). If elements are comparable and more mutation is permissible, you could sort in place (`O(n log n)`) and then scan to find and keep only the originally-duplicated elements. If the list is link-based, the scan is linear (`O(n)`). If it's array-based, you'd need to maintain a 'result tail' index and copy the selected 'to keep' elements to this tail position during the scan, before truncating, for `O(n)` (overall `O(n log n)`).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with checking, for each element, if it appears before it but not after. If it doesn't fit, then either it is not a duplicate or it is an other occurence of the duplicate  that you don't want to keep. Either cases we don't keep it.

```
def simplify(a_list):
    for i in range(len(a_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        value = a_list[i]
        if not value in a_list[:i] or value in a_list[i+1:]:
            del a_list[i]
```

Not sure if using slices fit your requirements though.

---

Usage:

```
>>> A = [1,2,1,3,4,5,4]
>>> simplify(A)
>>> A
[1, 4]
>>> A = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
>>> simplify(A)
>>> A
[1, 2]
>>> A = [1,1,1,1,1]
>>> simplify(A)
>>> A
[1]
>>> A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> simplify(A)
>>> A
[]
```

Comment: In python 2 I believe `range(...)` creates a list.

Comment: But `xrange` doesn't.

Comment: But slicing does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to get only the unique values and then remove them, one-by-one, from the original list - so that only the duplicates will remain:

```
a = [1,2,1,3,4,5,4]
s = list(set(a))
for x in s:
    a.remove(x)
print a # [1, 4]
```

Another elegant option which I 'stole' from [Ritesh Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15155286/1057429) is: 
collect only the items that appear more than once, use set to remove the dups, and wrap it with `list` to return a list as a result:

```
a = [1,2,1,3,4,5,4]
print list(set([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])) # [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need, barring clarification:

```
def find_duplicated_items(data):
    seen = set()
    duplicated = set()

    for x in data:
        if x in seen:
            duplicated.add(x)
        else:
            seen.add(x)

    return duplicated
```

It takes an iterable and returns a set; you can turn it into a list with `list(results)`.

**UPDATE:**

Here's another way of doing it, as a generator. Just because :).

```
from collections import Counter

def find_duplicated(iterable, atleast=2):
    counter = Counter()
    yielded = set()

    for item in iterable:
        counter[item] += 1
        if (counter[item] >= atleast) and (item not in yielded):
            yield item
            yielded.add(item)
```

Comment: Though the question only specifies no new 'list' be created, I would assume the requirement is that no new collection of any kind be made. Also it appears the requirement is for a method which mutates an existing list rather than creating a new one. This is exactly the right solution otherwise I think!

Comment: @ Oly 'Oil' Sourbut - Can you please explain the difference b/w creating a collection and creating a different list?

Comment: @Nidhi A ['collection'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collection_(abstract_data_type)) in computer science refers to a number of related data structures. A [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) is a kind of collection, representing a some items which have an order, and can usually be accessed by index (e.g. `a` is a list, I want `a[4]`, the 5th - counting from 0 - item in `a`). In my experience, a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) is the next most common kind of collection - it stores data with no particular order, and no repeats.

Comment: @Nidhi in many programming languages, the type system works like this: a 'collection' is a type which has methods to check if an item is contained in it, and can be iterated over. A 'list' is a collection, and also has methods to access items by index, and (if mutable) insert or remove items at a given index. A 'set' is a collection, and also has the [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(computer_science)) property that it contains no repeats. Often these types are specialised further - for example 'arraylist' or 'linkedlist' types might specialise the 'list' type.

Comment: @Nidhi, lists are good if you need order; sets are useful for making sure you only store one of each thing, or for membership testing; you can check if something is in a set much more efficiently than if something is in a list. There are also multisets, also called bags, of which `Counter` is an implementation; it can store a count for each item in a set.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to delete 2nd duplicates and non duplicates in place, yielding the old list containing only unique duplicates. I haven't thoroughly tested it.  Note that time required will scale as O(N**2) where N is the length of the input list.

Unlike other solutions, there are no new lists constructed here, not even a list for a for loop or list comprehension.

File: "dup.py"

```
def dups(mylist):
    idx = 0 
    while(idx<len(mylist)):
        delidx = idx+1
        ndeleted = 0
        while delidx < len(mylist):
            if mylist[delidx] == mylist[idx]:
                del mylist[delidx]
                ndeleted += 1
            else:
                delidx += 1
        if ndeleted==0:
            del mylist[idx]
        else:
            idx += 1
    return mylist
```

Usage (iPython)

```
In [1]: from dup import dups

In [2]: dups([1,1,1,1,1])
Out[2]: [1]

In [3]: dups([1,1,2,1,1])
Out[3]: [1]

In [4]: dups([1,1,2,2,1])
Out[4]: [1, 2]

In [5]: dups([1,1,2,1,2])
Out[5]: [1, 2]

In [6]: dups([1,2,3,1,2])
Out[6]: [1, 2]

In [7]: dups([1,2,1,3,4,5,4])
Out[7]: [1, 4]
```