# saving lines to file based on condition pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H577','H578','H600', 'H700', 'H700'],
  'CD': ['AAAAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEEEE','FFFFFFF','GGGGGGG']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

it looks like:

```
df
Out[9]: 
        CD    ID
0  AAAAAAA  H576
1    BBBBB  H577
2   CCCCCC  H577
3   DDDDDD  H578
4  EEEEEEE  H600
5  FFFFFFF  H700
6  GGGGGGG  H700
```

For each ID that has more than one CD values, i want to save them to a separate file.

**my desire output files:**

**H577.txt**

```
  CD      ID
 BBBBB   H577
 CCCCCC  H577
```

**H700.txt**

```
  CD       ID
 FFFFFFF  H700
 GGGGGGG  H700
```

my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H577','H578','H600', 'H700', 'H700'],
  'CD': ['AAAAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEEEE','FFFFFFF','GGGGGGG']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df1 = (df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: ('if CD has more than one value for the same ID'.any())))

df1.groupby('ID').apply(lambda gp: gp.to_csv('ID{}.txt'.format(gp.name), sep='\t', index=False))
```

i am not sure how to code the 'if CD has more than one value of the same ID' part.

Comment: This problem reduces to finding duplicates in a list for which a simple google search returns this: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list'. You have to apply that in the IDs list and from that point on, it's easy sailing.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis the answer from the post is for removing duplicates, in my case i don't want that, i'm still new at python and i am not sure how to fit the code in the lambda style either.

Comment: It does not but i can fetch it for you. What do you want df1 to be? A construction like df containing the duplicates only ?

Comment: so i would need to write a function to get the duplicate sets, what should it return? and once i get the function how should fit it to the lambda code?

Comment: why does it have to be a lambda code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
(df.groupby('ID')
   .filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1)
   .groupby('ID')
   .apply(lambda gp: gp.to_csv('ID{}.txt'.format(gp.name), sep='\t', index=False))
)
```

**Output**

IDH577.txt:

```
CD  ID
BBBBB   H577
CCCCCC  H577
```

IDH700.txt:

```
CD  ID
FFFFFFF H700
GGGGGGG H700
```