# Finding the highest duplicate element

Tags: python

> Given the list `lst` of positive integers, associate the largest duplicated element with the variable `max_dup`. If the list contains no duplicates, associate -1 with `max_dup`.

I understand how to sort the list and how to find the max but I am having trouble figuring out how to keep only duplicates in the list.

All the research I have done has given me functions to import, while I want to code all of the parts.

```
max_dup=lst[0]
max_count = lst.count(lst[0])
for i in range(1,len.lst-1)
    if lst.count(lst[i]) > max_count and lst[i] > max_dup:
        max_dup = lst[i]
        max_count = lst.count(lst(i))
        if max_dup == 1:
            max_dup = -1
```

Comment: "I want to code all of the parts" - Then do so.

Comment: To find the duplicates there are many good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-a-list

Comment: Many of these solutions involve importing functions, which I can't do

Comment: Yes, but there others that do not, for example take a look at the second solution which is written in pure python...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you

`a = [7, 4, 7, 2, 3, 7, 3]`

`a.sort()
max_dup = 1
max_ele = a[0]`
`for i in range(len(a) - 1):
  if a[i] == a[i + 1]:
    max_dup += 1
  else:
    max_dup = 1
    max_ele = a[i + 1]
print(max_dup)
print(max_ele)`

sorry about formatting