# How can I find the same/duplicate elements(with more than 1 word) in the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example I have a list:

```
lst = ["abc bca","bca abc","cde def"]
```

I want to consider the elements "abc bca" and "bca abc" same/duplicate, what should be the approach?

Comment: Is more than two words possible in same string?

Comment: I am trying to use 2 approaches but not able take it to the final stage. Like I have tried converting the list to string using : **str1 = ''.join(lst)** but don't know how to segregate the resultant string to check the duplicacy. Actually I am beginner in Pyhton, so do not know much about it. @CoryKramer

Comment: Yes @user1190882

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [' '.join(j) for j in set(tuple(sorted(i.split())) for i in lst)]
['abc bca', 'cde def']
```

The way this works is by first spliting the strings on whitespace

```
>>> [i.split() for i in lst]
[['abc', 'bca'], ['bca', 'abc'], ['cde', 'def']]
```

Then sort each sublist

```
>>> [tuple(sorted(i.split())) for i in lst]
[('abc', 'bca'), ('abc', 'bca'), ('cde', 'def')]
```

Lastly you can create a `set` since we converted to `tuple` which is hashable (whereas `list` is not).

```
>>> set(tuple(sorted(i.split())) for i in lst)
{('abc', 'bca'), ('cde', 'def')}
```

The outermost list comprehension simply uses `join` to recreate the whitespace-joined original strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = ["abc bca","bca abc","cde def"]
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> c
Counter({'abc bca': 1, 'cde def': 1, 'bca abc': 1})
>>> for i in c:
...     if c[i]>1:
...             print i
... 
>>> lst = ["abc","bca","bca","abc","cde","def"]
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> for i in c:
...     if c[i]>1:
...             print i
... 
abc
bca
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change yours strings to set of words:

```
>>> lst = ["abc bca","bca abc","cde def"]
>>> new_lst = [frozenset(x.split(' ')) for x in lst]
```

And then you can use just some [method of finding duplicates in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-a-list):

```
>>> print [item for item, count in collections.Counter(new_lst).items() if count > 1]
[frozenset(['abc', 'bca'])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "I want to consider the elements the same", but you could use this approach if you wanted to return a set of "unique" items:

```
original_list = ["abc bca", "bca abc", "cde def"]
modified_list = []

for original_one_item in original_list:
    original_one_items = original_one_item.split(' ')
    original_one_items.sort()
    modified_list.append(" ".join(original_one_items))

modified_list = set(modified_list)
```

This will remove the `"bca abc"` item from the first list and return a set.