# What accounts for the following behavior when using "print" in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import math as mat

 list_of_numbers = {int(mat.sqrt(x)) for x in range(7)}

 print(list_of_numbers)
```

I was expecting the output to be the square root of each number from zero to 6.

i.e., [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

Why is it that Python only prints

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

I have checked the documentation on print https://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php

It seems that there is no reference about print not printing duplicate values. Can anyone help?

Comment: Change `{}` to `[]`. `{}` is for set and `[]` is for list. Set will only have unique elements so the output is correct

Comment: maybe your problem is the same as in this thread? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-a-list>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a [set literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) here:

```
list_of_numbers = {int(mat.sqrt(x)) for x in range(7)}
```

Sets don't store duplicates. They're useful data structures for checking membership for things that can be hashed.

They are definitely not the same thing as lists.

To create a list, you just need to swap `{` and `}` for `[` and `]`:

```
 list_of_numbers = [int(mat.sqrt(x)) for x in range(7)]
```

Comment: This answer gives the OP an answer to why his code is not working, but doesn't give an actual solution to help him fix his code. Perhaps you could show him how to create a list?

Comment: fair enough. added.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using a Set instead of a List. Try:

```
import numpy as np
import math as mat

list_of_numbers = [int(mat.sqrt(x)) for x in range(7)]

print(list_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
list_of_numbers = {int(mat.sqrt(x)) for x in range(7)}
```

to

```
list_of_numbers = [int(mat.sqrt(x)) for x in range(7)]
```