# BeautifulSoup and if/else statements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

A am learning how to use BeautifulSoup and I have run into an issue with double printing in a loop I have written.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


page = 'https://news.google.com/news/headlines?gl=US&ned=us&hl=en'                 #main page

#url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")
r = requests.get(page)                              #requests html document
data = r.text                                       #set data = to html text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")           #parse data with BS


for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    #if contains /news/
    if ('/news/' in link.get('href')):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Examples:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
#if contains cointelegraph/news/
#if ('https://cointelegraph.com/news/' in link.get('href')):
url = link.get('href')                          #local var store url
if '/news/' in url:
    print(url)
    print(count)
    count += 1

if count == 5:
    break
```

output:

```
    https://cointelegraph.com/news/woman-in-denmark-imprisoned-for-hiring-hitman-using-bitcoin
0
https://cointelegraph.com/news/ethereum-price-hits-all-time-high-of-750-following-speed-boost
1
https://cointelegraph.com/news/ethereum-price-hits-all-time-high-of-750-following-speed-boost
2
https://cointelegraph.com/news/senior-vp-says-ebay-seriously-considering-bitcoin-integration
3
https://cointelegraph.com/news/senior-vp-says-ebay-seriously-considering-bitcoin-integration
4
```

For some reason my code keeps printing out the same url twice...

Comment: *I have run into an issue*, any specific one ?

Comment: maybe there are two elements on page so you get two prints. ie link with title and the same link with image.

Comment: your code seems to run as is.  please show what you expect as output

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and the provided link there seems to be duplicates in the results of BeautifulSoup `find_all` search. The html structure needs to be checked to see why duplicates are returned (check the `find_all` search options to filter some in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all). But if you want a quick fix and want to remove the duplicates from the printed results you can use the modified loop with a set as below to keep track of seen entries (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-a-list)).

```
In [78]: l = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a') if '/news/' in link.get('href')]

In [79]: any(l.count(x) > 1 for x in l)                                                                                                              
Out[79]: True
```

The above output shows duplicate exists in the list. Now to remove them use something like

```
seen = set()                                                                                                                                

for link in soup.find_all('a'):                                                                                                             

    lhref = link.get('href')
    if '/news/' in lhref and lhref not in seen:
        print lhref
        seen.add(lhref)
```