# 2 questions on Python : created table & fail to find duplicates in rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this data set which is in this format in this way in csv file:

[image]

1st question : I am trying to find duplicates rows in the table just created in python below?
I did try to use the set function to run the rows and the output I got is 
no duplicates even though there is a duplicate row in the data set.

2nd question:  is it possible to reference this table as i realized that it becomes a table when I print?So that I can use it on the next step for calculation purpose.

```
COL_1_WIDTH = 10
COL_2_WIDTH = 35
for row in data:
IC1 = len(str(row[0]))
IC2 = len(str(row[1]))
 print( str(row[0])+ str( (COL_1_WIDTH-IC1) *' ') +\
 str(row[1]) + str( (COL_2_WIDTH-IC2) *' ') +\
 str(row[2]))

for row in data:
 if len(set(row)) !=len(row):
 print ('duplicates: ', row)
else:
    print ('no duplicates:', row)
```

P.s. Permit to use built in function & numpy only.

Grateful for any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: `len(set(data)) != len(data)` will tell you if dupes, leaving you still some work to find out what are the dupes. (You're only checking one item at a time so len is always going to be one for set and non-set.)

Comment: Hi, thanks!, I just ran and changed it to data. Got error :TypeError: unhashable type: 'writeable void-scalar'

Comment: What kind of table is this (e.g. are you using Pandas)? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I am not using pandas. Use the built in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really explain what kind of object is 'data', so I assumed it was a list of strings. 
Here's how I created mine from a csv file:

```
with open('/home/sebastien/Documents/answerSO.csv') as file:
    data=file.read()    #a string

data=data.split('\n')   #a list of strings
data.pop()      #to delete the last element, an empty string
```

(note that using the csv module may be a better idea)

Now, to look for duplicates, I used the method explained here:
[How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

```
seen = set()
uniq = []
for row in data:
    if row not in seen:
        uniq.append(row)
        seen.add(row)
    else:
        print("found a duplicate:",row)
```

And about referencing it, well, it's in 'data'

Comment: Apologies, 'data' refers to the picture table with headers: quarter, type, value

Comment: Okay, but I meant in Python. If you juste run this script, it will raise a `NameError: name 'data' is not defined`

Comment: Thank you!, i tried running the script.   Encountered error in this row :if row not in seen:       TypeError: unhashable type: 'writeable void-scalar' which i did not understand. What i did, is place the block of scripts after I load the data. Before that, I exclude the new created table in the question.

Comment: I think I get it.  Could you print 'data' and send the result? My guess is there was a problem splitting it and you ended up with an unhasable object in row, so not the string I have. Surely, a difference with the convention for 'end of line' in csv. Mac uses '\r', and Windows '\r\n'.

Comment: I know why. I used 2nd block of your scripts and continued with the question script above.I use data= np.loadtxt to open the file. I am puzzled unable to use it. The question script output : 2007-Q1 <space>1-Small<space>1

Comment: I know why. I used 2nd block of your scripts and continued with the question script above. I use data= np.loadtxt to open the file. I am puzzled unable to use it. The ques. orginal script output : 2007-Q1 <space>1-Small<space>1. I modified ques.script output into: 2007-Q11-Small1 & follow up use your 2nd block script again. Trial with set() -> no result & set(data) but obtain error unhashable etc. Grateful if some idea.

Comment: Using numpy to process things other than numbers may not be a good idea. But if you juste run my whole script, it should do what you're asking for