# trying to find a way to delete or reveal similar references with python

Tags: python, text, ms-word

I have a question and I need your help.
I have a word file which contains many references like:

[1] M.-H. Han, Y. Li, and C.-H. Hwang, "The impact of high-frequency characteristics induced by intrinsic parameter fluctuations in nano-MOSFET device and circuit," Microelectronics Reliability, vol. 50, pp. 657-661, 2010.

[2] E. Maricau and G. Gielen, "Computer-aided analog circuit design for reliability in nanometer CMOS," Emerging and Selected Topics in Circuits and Systems, IEEE Journal on, vol. 1, pp. 50-58, 2011.
.
.
.

It would be possible that some of these references are similar but their numbers be different. 
do you have any idea to find a way to delete or reveal similar references with #python?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you defining "similar"? Are these references similar? If not, can you give examples  that are, and explain why they count as similar?

Comment: Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question

Comment: See [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the footnote text into a number and the rest of the reference:

```
>>> footnote = '[1] P. Wood, "Example Thesis," Some collection, pp 45-46, 2018'
>>> number, reference = footnote.split(' ', 1)
>>> reference
'P. Wood, "Example Thesis," Some collection, pp 45-46, 2018'
```

Python has a [**`Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class which is useful for building histograms.

You can add the references to a `Counter` object and then query it for when there is more than one:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> counter = Counter()
>>> counter[reference] += 1
```

You can create a loop of all your footnotes:

```
>>> for footnote in footnotes:
...     number, reference = footnote.split(' ', 1)
...     counter[reference] += 1
```

Then access the counts that are greater than `1`:

```
>>> duplicates = [item for item, count in counter.most_common()
...               if count > 1]
```