# Display only the element with no duplicate

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates

How can I return only the element/s with no duplicate in the list?

```
e.g.

list = [1,4,5,1,5] to [4]
```

Comment: You can find some very good clues on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9836685/102937).

Comment: Or from [another answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49865122/1270789), then `list(set(uniques)-set(dups))`.

Comment: write a function `def uniques(x): a,b=np.unique(x,return_counts=1);return a[b==1]`  then use it: `uniques( [1,4,5,1,5])`

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter()`

```
from collections import Counter as counter 
list = [1,4,5,1,5]
c = counter(list)

print(*[item for item, time in c.items() if time==1], sep='\n')
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
4
```

Comment: we can do it in a more simple manner.

Comment: for sure we can but simple doesn't always mean the fastest one

Answer (score 0):

```
def unique(list1):
for i in list1:
    if(list1.count(i)==1):
        return i 
list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]  
print(unique(list1))


list2 =[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5]  
print(unique(list2))
```