# Extract Duplicates from List After Applying Sort

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am working on code snippet to extract duplicates from a list. I have seen several implementations/solutions on this site. However, I am not getting this line correctly - syntax wise I think. After sorting, compare index(x) with index(x+1). If it is add to the set.

`print(set([i for i in a if (a[i] == a[i+1]))`

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
print(a)
print(set(sorted(a)))
# l1[i] == l1[i+1]
print(set([i for i in a if (a[i] == a[i+1]))
print(set([i for i in a if sum([1 for item in a if item == i]) > 1]))
```

Expected results: {1, 2, 5}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Comment: I am specifically trying this logic print(set([i for i in a if (a[i] == a[i+1])). I am aware of many different ways to extract the dups.

Answer (score 5):

you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
c = Counter(a)

res = [n for n, m in c.items() if m > 1]
print(res)  # [1, 2, 5]
```

this way you iterate once over the list and once over the counter only.

Comment: From a complexity perspective, this is the way to go.

Comment: I keep forgetting `Counter` exists. This is better +1

Answer (score 2):

From what I could gather you are trying to implement this logic, this code runs in `O(nlogn)` time complexity while the code which runs with counter runs in `O(n)` time complexity means it is faster and cleaner.

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
a.sort()
print(set([a[i] for i in range(len(a)-1) if (a[i] == a[i+1])]) )
```

OUTPUT

```
set([1, 2, 5])
```

Comment: How can `O(n log n)` be faster than `O(n)`?

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead?

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
duplicates = set(element for element in a if a.count(element) > 1)
print(duplicates)
```

Output:

```
{1, 2, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a simple solution to find duplicates from List.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
>>> a.sort()
>>> set([x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1])
```

Output: `{1, 2, 5}`