# Python program to get only the unique which has no duplicate from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

consider I have a list in python `list1=[123,123,724,458,458]`, I want the output as

`list1=[724]`, the only unique value in list

```
list1=[100,200,300,300,100];
list1=set(list1);
```

Gives me

```
list1=[100,200,300]
```

But I need

```
list1=[200]
```

as output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the frequencies of each item in the list, and then select only with frequency 1

```
from collections import Counter


def get_unique(li):
    #Create the counter to count frequencies
    c = Counter(li)

    #Create a list of items with count 1
    result = [key for key,value in c.items() if value == 1]

    return result

print(get_unique([100,200,300,300,100]))
print(get_unique([123,123,724,458,458]))
```

The output will be

```
[200]
[724]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension. But you have to keep two objects, your initial list and your list of unique elements. The `count` method give the number of occurrence of one element in the list.

Here is one way to do:

```
list1 = [100, 200, 300, 300, 100]

# Convert again to list
list1_unique = list(set(list1))

ans = [unique for unique in list1_unique if list1.count(unique) == 1]
print(ans)
# [200]
```

Comment: Why not simply `[unique for unique in list1 if list1.count(unique) == 1]`?

Comment: Yes @SupratimHaldar , even simpler !