# UDF function to check whether my input dataframe has duplicate columns or not using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I need to return boolean false if my input dataframe has duplicate columns with the same name. I wrote the below code. It identifies the duplicate columns from the input dataframe and returns the duplicated columns as a list. But when i call this function it must return boolean value i.e., if my input dataframe has duplicate columns with the same name it must return flase.

```
@udf('string')
def get_duplicates_cols(df, df_cols):
    duplicate_col_index = list(set([df_cols.index(c) for c in df_cols if df_cols.count(c) == 2]))
    for i in duplicate_col_index:
      df_cols[i] = df_cols[i] + '_duplicated'
      df2 = df.toDF(*df_cols)
    cols_to_remove = [c for c in df_cols if '_duplicated' in c]
    return cols_to_remove
duplicate_cols = udf(get_duplicates_cols,BooleanType())
```

Comment: why use udf? Can be done without udf as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any UDF, you simple need a Python function. The check will be in Python not in JVM. So, as @Santiago P said you can use checkDuplicate **ONLY**

```
    def checkDuplicate(df):
        return len(set(df.columns)) == len(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you pass the data frame to the function.

```
udf(returnType=BooleanType())
    def checkDuplicate(df):
        return len(set(df.columns)) == len(df.columns)
```

Comment: it's not returning any value. It must return false if my input dataframe contains contains any duplicate columns.

Comment: This solution give you what you ask, `False` if there are duplicates, `True` if there are no duplicates columns. I think you are mixing things. In your code, you are trying to return a list of names (`ArrayType(StringType()`) of the duplicates columns. You can't return different types depending on the result (in a udf). `df.columns` give you a list of the columns in the dataframe, if you want the duplicates values I suggest reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)