# How to count duplicates in a multidimensional list

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have a multidimensional list that I would like to return the max count or 2 or more duplicates but I dkmt know what code to use. For example I have a list

```
A=[[a,b],[b,c],[g,i],[a,c],[a,b],[a,b],[b,c]]
```

I would like my result to be something like this for the max duplicates

```
B=[a,b]
```

And I would like my result to be something like this as well for 2 or more duplicates

```
B=[[a,b],[b,c]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Comment: not really. that will only help if someone has a flatten list. i just trying to return the most appear duplicates or 2 or more duplicates in my list