# how can I get the number of list items that occur more than once?

Tags: python

In a list, they are many items, and some of them can occur more than once.
How can I get the number of those items which occur multiple times in a list, in Python?
For example, in below list, a and b occur multiple times. So in this case, I get two.

```
list = [ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'h', 'u', 'i', 'x', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'j', 'w' ]
```

Comment: What about 'e' and 'h', which also appear multiple times?

Comment: Yes sorry, then I must have made a mistake. The point is, how many items repeat within a given list.

Comment: So fix the question?

Answer (score 3):

Since the `Counter` solution is already taken, here's something different:

```
>>> lst.sort()
>>> len(set(lst[::2]) & set(lst[1::2]))
4
```

This first sorts, so then equal values are next to each other. Meaning a duplicated value appears both in the even-index places and in the odd-index places, so intersection them gets me all duplicated values (and of course none of the unique values, as those are either at an even index *or* at an odd index, not at both).

This has complexity O(n log n) due to sorting, of course, so at least for large lists I'd expect it to be slower than the `Counter` solution with its O(n) complexity.

Comment: I like this. Would you elaborate on how this works?

Comment: @zabop Added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835819/8565438) to the question [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9835762/8565438), can do:

```
import collections
print(len([item for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items() if count > 1]))
```

You get `4` because that is how many items are repeated in the list (ie `a, b, e, h` all appear more than once).

Can use other solutions from the thread of the linked question.