# Get list of lists of duplicates' indices

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list that contains duplicate elements. For all duplicate elements, I would like to obtain a list of their indices. The final output should be a list of lists of duplicate indices.

I have already come up with a working solution, but I have the feeling, that there **might be a more computationally efficient and/or sparse way (using less code)**  for this problem:

```
# set up a list that contains duplicate elements
a = ['bar','foo','bar','foo','foobar','barfoo']

# get list of elements that appear more than one time in the list
seen = {}
dupes = []

for x in a:
    if x not in seen:
        seen[x] = 1
    else:
        if seen[x] == 1:
            dupes.append(x)
        seen[x] += 1

# for each of those elements, return list of indices of matching elements
# in original list
dupes_indices = []

for dupe in dupes:
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == dupe]
    dupes_indices.append(indices)
```

where `dupes_indices` is `[[0, 2], [1, 3]]` (`'foo'` appears at indices 0 and 2 and `'bar'` appears at indices 1 and 3)

I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9835819/8792159) and [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294205/8792159) answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this nested `list` comprehension one-liner:

```
a = ['bar','foo','bar','foo','foobar','barfoo']
print([y for y in [[i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == x] for x in set(a)] if len(y) > 1])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas selection is great for such solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['bar','foo','bar','foo','foobar','barfoo'])
df.columns = ["elements"]
elements = set(df.elements.tolist())

for e in elements:
    x = df.loc[df.elements == e]
    print(e, x.index.tolist())
```

output

```
bar [0, 2]
foobar [4]
foo [1, 3]
barfoo [5]
```