# How to find the repeated items of a tuple in python

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, repeat

```
tup=(1,3,4,32,1,1,1)  
for i in tup:
    if tup.count(i) > 1:
        print('REPEATED')
```

[Image of what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4qXW.png)

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: your code already works ? or do you also want to know which elements are repeated ? or at which index ?

Comment: yes what elements are repeating i want to show them too

Comment: You code goes through the items, and each time it sees the number 1, which is in there more than once, it prints "REPEATED"

Comment: if you replace 'REPEATED' with `i`, you will print the number 1 four times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tup=(1,3,4,32,1,1,1,31,32,12,21,2,3)  
for i in tup:
    if tup.count(i) > 1:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

for k, v in Counter(tup).items():
    if v > 1:
        print("Repeated: {}".format(k))
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-2af82d4d1208> in <module>
      4 for k, v in Counter(tup).items():
      5   if v > 1:
----> 6       print("Repeated: " + k)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 0):

```
var=int(input())
tup=(10, 8, 5, 2, 10, 15, 10, 8, 5, 8, 8, 2)  
a=list(tup)
for i in range(len(a)):
  a[i]=int(a[i])
count=a.count(var)
print(var,'appears',count,'times in the tuple')
```

**Sample Input**

8

**Sample Output**

8 appears 4 times in the tuple

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way to do this is to use collections.Counter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> t = (1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
>>> c = Counter(t)
>>> c
Counter({1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1})
```

Counter returns a dict-like object that can be iterated through, along with other operations.