# python ternary formatted like for x in a if x in var or var.add(x)

Tags: python, duplicates

In searching for a method to find the duplicate entries in a list in python someone posted a solution that works in python and I cant decipher the ternary logic.

The post was here
[How do I find the duplicates in a list and create another list with them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)

The code is:

```
seen = set()
dupes = [x for x in list if x in seen or seen.add(x)]
```

The original poster helpful showed what it equates to:

```
dupes = []
for x in list:
    if x in seen:
        dupes.append(x)
    else:
        seen.add(x)
```

I cant find any reference googling around to a ternary of the form if x .... or ...

Can someone help me break down all the logic here?

I roughly understand how dupes = [x equates to dupes.append(x) when 'if x in seen' is True.

But I cant sort out how the 'or seen.add(x)' equates to calling else: seen.add(x) when x was not found in the seen list and thus adds nothing to the dupes list.

Comment: "I don't recommend the latter style, because it is not obvious what not seen.add(x) is doing" (from linked answer)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a "ternary form". Transliterated, this is simply:

```
seen = set()
dupes = []
for x in list:
    if x in seen or seen.add(x):
        dupes.append(x)
```

So, a list comprehension is of the form:

```
[<mapping expression> for <target> in <iterable expression> if <conditional expression>]
```

Here, `x in seen or seen.add(x)` is simply a conditional expression, which is equivalent to:

```
(x in seen) or seen.add(x)
```

This is relies on the [semantics of boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), in this case, for:

```
x or y
```

Will evaluate to `x` if `x` is truthy, else, it will evaluate to `y`. In the construction above, if `x in seen` is true, `seen.add(x)` is never evaluated. And the condition is true, and `x` is added to the list, otherwise, `seen.add(x)` is evaluated, but that expression returns `None`, so the whole conditional is false, and `x` is not added to the list.

This is the sort of list comprehension that would never pass a sane code review, if only for the fact that it relies on a side effect, which makes it confusing (list comprehensions should express functional, mapping/filtering operations, if you have side effects, *just use a for-loop*)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed breakdown. I am fairly new to python and "would not pass a code review" is reason enough for me to not spend the time trying to make sure I learn how this works to be able to reuse  a form like this to solve a problem later. Ill stick with more clear/straight forward ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty awful way to find the duplicates in the list, as that original answer says, but let's break it down:

We have the following clause:

```py
if x in seen or seen.add(x)
```

For each element, we check whether `x` is in `seen`. If so, it's a duplicate. We stop evaluating the expression and add it to the list.

If `x` is not in `seen`, it's not a duplicate. We add it to our `seen` set. `.add()` returns `None`, which is a falsy value. So, the element isn't added to our duplicates list, since at this point we have an expression which is equivalent to `False or None`, which evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a set:

```
s = set()
print(s.add(1))
# None
print(bool(s.add(2)))
# False
```

For `if x in seen or seen.add(x)` in your question, if statement first judges `x in seen`. If it gets true, it adds `x` to the list. Otherwise, due to the existence of or, it will continue to judge `bool(seen.add(x))`, the method `add` will be called and get `False`, so `x` will not be added to the list.