# Select columns with duplicated names pandas like "column 'a' plus any column whose name appears more than once"

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select certain columns even if duplicated while keeping the same names

```
col_select = ["a","x","x","x"]
   a  x  x  x  z
0  6  2  7  7  8
1  6  6  3  1  1
2  6  6  7  5  6
3  8  3  6  1  8
4  5  7  5  3  0
```

desired output

```
   a  x  x  x 
0  6  2  7  5
1  6  6  3  1
2  6  6  7  5
3  8  3  6  1
4  5  7  5  3
```

```
df[col_select]
boolen = []
col_commun = []
for i in range(0,len(col_select)):
    #print(i)
    boolen.append(col_select[i] in df.columns)
    if boolen[i] == True:
        col_commun.append(col_select[i])
        
df_out= df.loc[:,col_commun]
```

Comment: i need to select 'a' and 'x' in my case

Comment: Why do you have duplicate columns names in the first place? It seems like this will make lots of things difficult with this dataframe.

Comment: @Barmar The initial title was "Select columns with duplicated names pandas". That's why I was confused why 'a' should be selected, even if not duplicated.

Comment: @DataJanitor I was reading the text of the question, which says "even if duplicated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
out = df.loc[:,df.columns.duplicated(keep = False) | df.columns.isin(['a'])]
                                                       
   a  x  x  x
0  6  2  7  7
1  6  6  3  1
2  6  6  7  5
3  8  3  6  1
4  5  7  5  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them) to identify duplicates in column names. Then just add any non-duplicate columns you want to keep to that list, and select as you would usually:

```
from collections import Counter

duplicated_cols = [col for col, count in Counter(df.columns).items() if count > 1]
df_out = df.loc[:, ["a"] + duplicated_cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

`drop` unique columns except 'a'

```
uniq_cols = df.columns.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
out = df.drop(uniq_cols.drop('a'), axis=1)
```

out:

```
    a   x   x   x
0   6   2   7   7
1   6   6   3   1
2   6   6   7   5
3   8   3   6   1
4   5   7   5   3
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [[6, 2, 7, 7, 8], [6, 6, 3, 1, 1], [6, 6, 7, 5, 6], 
         [8, 3, 6, 1, 8], [5, 7, 5, 3, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['a', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'z'])
```