# How to tackle the Birthday Paradox Problem in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, nested-loops, birthday-paradox

I'm practicing the Birthday Paradox problem in Python. I've run it a bunch of times, with **changing the random number of birthdays** and **loop run number **, but the **probability is either 0 or 100%**, and I was unable to get other probability like 50% etc. Can someone help me look through my code and see what I did wrong? Thank you so much!!

```
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


first_day_of_year = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
num_of_ppl = 45
birthdays = []

# get 45 random birthdays list
for i in range(num_of_ppl):
    new_birthday = first_day_of_year + timedelta(days = randint(0, 365))
    birthdays.append(new_birthday)


# find if there's matched birthdays, run 10000 times
dups = 0 
duplicates = set()
for i in range(10000):
    for bday in birthdays:
        if birthdays.count(bday) > 1:
            duplicates.add(bday)
    if len(duplicates) >= 1:
        dups += 1


# calculate the probability
probability = dups/10000 * 100
print(probability)
```

Comment: You're looping 10000 times but it's with the same set of birthdays; you're not re-generating a new set of birthdays each time. You could loop a billion times and it wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate the birthdays list each time, the probability is as expected. Also I didn't see a need to use `datetime` or `set` objects, I just replaced them with `int`s and `bool`s without changing anything functionally. Also, you can use list comprehension in order to generate the birthdays list in one line:

```py
from random import randint

num_iterations = 10000
num_people = 45
num_duplicates_overall = 0

# generate a random birthday for each person, check if there was a duplicate,
# and repeat num_iterations times
for i in range(num_iterations):
    # start with a new, empty list every time.
    # get a list of random birthdays, of length num_people.
    birthdays = [randint(0, 365) for _ in range(num_people)]
    # Keep track of whether or not there was a duplicate for this iteration
    was_duplicate = False
    for bday in birthdays:
        if birthdays.count(bday) > 1:
            # We found a duplicate for this iteration, so we can stop checking
            was_duplicate = True
            break
    if was_duplicate:
        num_duplicates_overall += 1

probability = num_duplicates_overall / num_iterations
print(f"Probability: {probability * 100}%")
```

Output with `num_iterations = 1000000` and `num_people = 23`:

```
Probability: 50.6452%
```

Edit: Alternatively, there's [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541827/6273251) to check for duplicates which is supposedly faster (but mainly I like it because it's on one line):

```py
if len(birthdays) != len(set(birthdays)):
    num_duplicates_overall += 1
```

So, your code could look as simple as this:

```py
from random import randint

num_iterations = 10000
num_people = 45
num_duplicates_overall = 0

for i in range(num_iterations):
    birthdays = [randint(0, 365) for _ in range(num_people)]
    if len(birthdays) != len(set(birthdays)):
        num_duplicates_overall += 1

probability = num_duplicates_overall / num_iterations
print(f"Probability: {probability * 100}%")
```