# Return duplicates in each sublist (2d list)

Tags: python, dataframe, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a large 2d list that has duplicates in some sublist.  I would like to return only duplicates. For instance,

```
 Df =[[2,3,5,20],[5,10,20,10],[4,13,15,15,17,34,17],[33,34,15,21]]
```

I would like my results like this. If possible

```
 Result = [[5,10,10,20],[4,13,15,15,17,17,34]]
```

Comment: how to define duplicate and why your result is [[5,10,10,20],[4,13,15,15,17,17,34]]

Comment: Because it has duplicates inside the list

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541827/1609514) you can check if a list contains duplicates by comparing its length to a set of only the unique items.

```
def contains_duplicates(x):
    return len(x) != len(set(x))

assert contains_duplicates([1, 2, 3]) is False
assert contains_duplicates([1, 2, 2]) is True

result = [x for x in Df if contains_duplicates(x)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[5, 10, 20, 10], [4, 13, 15, 15, 17, 34, 17]]
```

Answer (score 1):

if one list has duplicates, that means len(t) > len(set(t)

```
Df =[[2,3,5,20],[5,10,20,10],[4,13,15,15,17,34,17],[33,34,15,21]]
res = [t for t in Df if len(t) > len(set(t))]
print(res)
```

output

```
[[5, 10, 20, 10], [4, 13, 15, 15, 17, 34, 17]]
```